# MethodError when trying to add numbers of different types

Tags: julia

```
function random_step(x, dx)
    num=randn(1)
    return x + num*dx
end

random_step(1, 1)
```

Running this code gives me:

```
julia> random_step(1, 1)
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching +(::Int32, ::Array{Float64,1})       
For element-wise addition, use broadcasting with dot syntax: scalar .+ array
Closest candidates are:
  +(::Any, ::Any, ::Any, ::Any...) at operators.jl:538
  +(::T, ::T) where T<:Union{Int128, Int16, Int32, Int64, Int8, UInt128, UInt16, UInt32, UInt64, UInt8} at int.jl:86
  +(::Union{Int16, Int32, Int8}, ::BigInt) at gmp.jl:531
  ...
Stacktrace:
 [1] random_step(::Int32, ::Int32) at .\REPL[1]:3
 [2] top-level scope at REPL[2]:1
```

So i assume when I jsut enter 1, teh data type is not Float64 which randn is.  So how can I make variables quickly in julia an control their data type?  I often need to do that for debugging code.  Also  will this be a problem for me going forward with julia?  I thought it was like python, do I often have to fiddle with the datatypes being used and passed between functions?

Comment: Python will tell you quite the same thing if you try to add a number and a list. What Julia doesn't do, though, is to broadcast without you explicitely asking for it, like Numpy would.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is that randn(1) produces an Array{Float64,1} and not a Float64.

If you add two scalars, even if they are not of the same type, one of them (or both) will be promoted as you expect, for example:

```
 julia> 1 + 1.0
 2.0
```

However, there is no clear rule to add one array and one scalar, which is what you are trying to do.

### What went wrong?

The function randn(1) creates an array with elements of type Float64, and not only one element.

You can see the documentation for randn and see why:

```
help?> randn
search: randn rand transcode macroexpand @macroexpand1 @macroexpand CartesianIndex CartesianIndices

  randn([rng=GLOBAL_RNG], [T=Float64], [dims...])

  Generate a normally-distributed random number of type T with mean 0 and standard deviation 1. Optionally
  generate an array of normally-distributed random numbers.
```

So by calling with (1) you are specifying that you want a 1 dimensional array where the only dimension has one element.

### How to fix it?

You should define your function as

```
function random_step(x, dx)
    num=randn()
    return x + num*dx
end
```

Note that I am calling `rand()`, which returns a Float64 instead of `rand(1)` which returns an Array with elements of the type Float64.

Doing that, you can see that your example works:

```
julia> function random_step(x, dx)
           num=randn()
           return x + num*dx
       end
random_step (generic function with 1 method)

julia> random_step(1, 1)
1.5813972833750205
```